# At what stage will I get the Porsche Cayman S in Need for Speed: Hot Pursuit?

Tags: need-for-speed-hot-pursuit-2010

I have the limited edition of the game, so I already have the cop version of the Porsche Cayman S, but I would like to know how to get the racing version. Has anyone unlocked this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> The racer version of the Porsche Cayman S is available through a promotion with Dr Pepper and is XBOX 360 only. Look for further details soon.
>   From: http://hotpursuit.needforspeed.com/game-info/cars/porsche-cayman-s

So it looks like there isn't one for the majority of us :)